# Merging many statistical methods for Text classification, starting with SVM multiclass classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, sentiment-analysis

Premise: I am not an expert of Machine Learning/Maths/Statistics. I am a linguist and I am entering the world of ML. Please when answering, try to be the more explicit you can.

My problem: I have 3000 expressions containing some aspects (or characteristics, or features) that users usually review in online reviews. These expressions are recognized and approved by human beings and experts.

> Example: “they play a difficult role”

The labels are: Acting (referring to the act of acting and also to actors), Direction, Script, Sound, Image.

The goal: I am trying to classify these expressions according to their aspects.

My system: I am using SkLearn and Python under a Jupyter environment.

Technique used until now:

1. I built a bag-of-words matrix (so I kept track of the
   presence/absence of – stemmed - words for each expression) and
2. I applied a SVM multiclass classifier with kernel RBF and C = 1 (or I
   tuned according to the final accuracy.). The code used is this one from
   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiclass-classification-using-scikit-learn/

First attempt showed 0.63 of accuracy. When I tried to create more labels from the class Script accuracy went down to 0.50. I was interested in doing that because I have some expressions that for sure describe the plot or the characters. 
I think that the problem is due to the presence of some words that are shared among these aspects.

I searched for a solution to improve the model. I found something called “learning curve”. I use the official code provided by sklearn documentation http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html .

The result is like the second picture (the right one). I can't understand if it is good or not.

In addition to this, I would like to:

1. import the expressions from a text file. For the moment I have
   just created an array and put inside the expressions and I don't
   feel so comfortable.
2. find a way, if it possible, to communicate to the system that there are some words that are very specific / important to an Aspect and help it to improve the classification.

How can I do this? I read that in some works researchers have used more systems... How should I handle this? From where can I retrieve the resulting numbers from the first system to use them in the second one?

I would like to underline that there are some expressions, verbs, nouns, etc. that are used a lot in some contexts and not in others. There are some names that for sure are names of actors and not directors, for example.  In the future I would like to add more linguistic pieces of information to the system and trying to improve it.

I hope to have expressed myself in an enough clear way and to have used an appropriate and understandable language.

Comment: Interesting question but you might get better responses if you try on [DS SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Stedy I will try it then!